# VBA - Excel Forces Restart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am having a major issue with my code that is supposed to reset the worksheets, not shut down the entire workbook and force a restart.  This has not been an issue, and has only occured since I added the last bit of code starting at `On Error Resume Next`.

```
Sub Reset()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Set Up" Or ws.Name = "Report" Then
            Else:
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets("Report").Cells.ClearContents

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Charts.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this line is the problem I guess: `ThisWorkbook.Charts.Delete` You cannot delete a built-in collection like this at all. You should loop through it and delete the charts one by one

Comment: So something along the lines of `For each Charts in Thisworkbook  If Charts.Name = "Locations" Then Charts.Delete`

Comment: I really gave you where the problem is and how to fix it here without even writing it as an answer. Plus, I wrote you an answer and then you gave more details of what you have as charts and then I commented on that and told you what to do simply and very easily. In both cases, you ignore my comments and someone else is putting the same thing in the answer section and you chose it as the answer. It is amazing how helping some folks here feel like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this deletes the charts in a workhseet, say activesheet for example:

```
Sub DeleteallCharts() 
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject 
    For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        chtObj.Delete 
    Next 
End Sub
```

if you want to delete all of the charts in the workbook, then you have to loop through the worksheet too like this:

```
Sub DeleteallChartsInWorkbook() 
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject 
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS in Thisworkbook.Worksheets
        For Each chtObj In WS.ChartObjects
            chtObj.Delete 
        Next chtObj 
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Each chart is it's own sheet, it is not embedded.

Comment: Then you can use `thisworkbook.sheets` instead of `thisworkbook.worksheets` in your code. Sheets can be worksheet or chart. There is no need to delete charts separately. If it worked, then let me know so that I can change my answer

Comment: I appreciate your help. I awarded you the fake internet points.

Answer (score 2):

If you have chart sheets, then you should use the following code:

```
Sub DeleteChartSheets()

    Dim ch As Chart

    For Each ch In ThisWorkbook.Charts
        ch.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```